# Module not found: Can't resolve 'Umma.PNG' in 'C:\Users\Zaid Mohammed\Ummanetic\ummanetic\src'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to import an image from the source file "Umma.PNG" , on the code if you hover the cursor on the link  it shows the image however on the executable page its returning this error ./src/Header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'Umma.PNG' in 'C:\Users\Zaid Mohammed\Ummanetic\ummanetic\src'

[image: The error image]

Can anyone help me insert the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image should be imported with the full path.
eg: "../../image/umma.png"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign the files directly(as a static link). You need to import it like an file or library.

```
import MyImage from './where/is/image/path/umma.png'
```

And you can use it like below:

```
<img src={MyImage} alt="its an image" />
```